Grammar analysis of a sentence - appositive or complement
Could you please analyze the grammatical functions of 'and one that inspires me' and 'that we can right some of these wrongs' in the entire sentence as follows?

Every day about 300,000 cars move through the area of the forthcoming wildlife bridge. “Someone could be in rush-hour traffic, and there could be a mountain lion right above them,” said project planner and urban ecologist with the National Wildlife Federation Beth Pratt, according to The Guardian. “I think that's such a hopeful image， and one that inspires me that we can right some of these great wrongs.” - Source.

R. Quirk's Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language mentions the concept of coordinative apposition. Can this sentence be understood as the indefinite pronoun 'one' serving as a substitute, in coordinative apposition with the preceding 'a hopeful image'? Can the following 'that we can right some of these wrongs' also be understood as an appositive of 'a hopeful image'?
Thank you!

Please look up the actual definition of an apposition.

Consider:  A cupcake is a tasty treat, and one that takes little time to make.

Apposition is a matter of debate, but by my lights, the following is not apposition but a somewhat garbled  ungrammatical sentence because it has lost track of the subject of the verb.

I think that's such a hopeful image， and one that inspires me that we can right some of these great wrongs.

I would parse it so:

I think that is such a hopeful image
--  and [it is] one that inspires me
[to believe?] that we can right some of these great wrongs.

"that we can right some of these  great wrongs" is an odd complement to "inspires me":

one that inspires me that we can right some of these great wrongs.

We cannot take "that we can right some of these greagt wrongs" as a declarative content clause:

that we can right some of these great wrongs inspires me

because of "and one".  "One", not the that-clause, is the subject of "inspires".
P.S. It could be easily fixed by changing "and one that" to "and it":

I think that's such a hopeful image， and it inspires me that we can right some of these great wrongs.

Then the that-clause becomes a content clause (  "that we can right some of these great wrongs inspires me"   with dummy "it" ) and the sentence is made whole.

It is most definitely not ungrammatical in spoken English, just poorly punctuated:  “I think that's such a hopeful image, and one that inspires me — that we can right some of these great wrongs.” But it isn't apposition.

@Lambie  Looking forward to your answer where you show it is grammatical.   As it stands, the fragment separated from the first part by the em-dash is just dangling there -- to what does "that" refer if you understand it as relative pronoun, or what does the that-clause complement if you think it is a clausal complement?  Do you understand it is as a content-clause?  If so, how is it integrated into the earlier part?

It's just connected speech and sounds fine as a spoken utterance. But wouldn't work in writing. When people speak off the cuff, many things can happen. elision, truncation, saying things out of order, etc. etc. etc. There are many ways it can be all linked together or punctuated and you have found one of them above.

@Lambie I don't think your punctuation truly remedies it; it simply identifies it as an off-the-cuff remark that requires the listener to be somewhat forgiving of its ungrammaticality..

It's refreshing to see 'T₁ is a matter of debate' rather than an unattributed fiat from a particular grammar (whose authors may well justify their interpretations and recommend grammars etc containing differing interpretations and terminology).

Theis sentence becomes readable and grammatical, provided the punctuation is adjusted. The part "and one that inspires me" corresponds exactly to parenthetical information, that is in the present case, information that is not needed. Through the use of an M-dash parenthetical, the flow of the sentence becomes clear.

(Merriam-Webster) What is an Em Dash?
The em dash (—) can function like a comma, a colon, or parenthesis. Like commas and parentheses, em dashes set off extra information, such as examples, explanatory or descriptive phrases, or supplemental facts. Like a colon, an em dash introduces a clause that explains or expands upon something that precedes it.


I think that's such a hopeful image—and one that inspires me—that we can right some of these great wrongs.

This could be said almost equivalently as below.

I think that's such a hopeful image that we can right some of these great wrongs; it is also one that inspires me.

Dashes seem to be preferable because of the interruption in the syntax ("I think that's such a hopeful image that we can": no interruption of the correlative subordinator construction with "such … that").

(CoGEL III.20 Dashes and parentheses)
[…]
The comma is the least obtrusive correlative mark and for that reason is
preferred unless there is a disruption of the syntactic structure of the clause or the danger of confusion with other neighbouring commas or of failure to mark adequately a rather lengthy inclusion. In these cases dashes or
parentheses are preferable, except that dashes tend to give a somewhat more
dramatic and informal impression, suggesting an impromptu aside, rather
than a planned inclusion :

At that time, the students - goodness knows for what reason - reversed their earlier, more moderate decision, and a big demonstration was planned. [1]

In [I] the inclusion is sufficiently informal an interruption to justify dashes rather than parentheses.
Under certain circumstances, even short included items tend to be enclosed
by parentheses.

"One" should be understood as replacing "image".

I'd say that the basic question here is whether 'X inspires me that Y' is acceptable, patterning on 'X encourages/ed me that Y' as in 'this partial success encourages me that I'm on the right track'. Some examples involving 'inspires' can be found on the internet.

@EdwinAshworth I know that examples can be found, but "inspire O +that" and "encourage O + that" are not found in OALD, and  I do have the impression that  these constructions do not sound good; I am not at all used to finding them.

I'm pretty familiar with 'encourages me that'. There are plenty of examples of 'encouraged him that', often from religious groups, but including even one from St Helens Borough Council.

@EdwinAshworth See my answer where I don't parse it as 'X inspires me that Y'. In the most salient interpretation, the last that-clause elaborates the content of 'hopeful image' and 'image that inspires me', which is why it's call a content clause.


I think that's such a hopeful image, and one that inspires me that we can right some of these great wrongs.

The only way to parse this sentence as a grammatical one is by analyzing the that-clause (that we can right some of these great wrongs) as a complement of the nominal hopeful image and image that inspires me. Traditional Grammar would classify it as involving apposition, but The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language would classify it as involving complementation (p. 964-965):

4.5 Complement of a noun or supplement Content clauses commonly function as complement in NP structure:[33] i [The thought t̲h̲a̲t̲ ̲w̲e̲ ̲m̲i̲g̲h̲t̲ ̲n̲e̲e̲d̲ ̲h̲i̲m̲] had simply never occurred to him. ii He expressed [the opinion t̲h̲a̲t̲ ̲w̲e̲ ̲s̲h̲o̲u̲l̲d̲ ̲a̲d̲v̲e̲r̲t̲i̲s̲e̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲ ̲p̲o̲s̲i̲t̲i̲o̲n̲ ̲o̲v̲e̲r̲s̲e̲a̲s̲].  iii We’re looking for [evidence t̲h̲a̲t̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲ ̲f̲i̲r̲e̲ ̲w̲a̲s̲ ̲d̲e̲l̲i̲b̲e̲r̲a̲t̲e̲l̲y̲ ̲l̲i̲t̲].For the distinction between this construction and one with a relative clause modifier  (e.g. evidence t̲h̲a̲t̲ ̲w̲i̲l̲l̲ ̲c̲o̲n̲v̲i̲n̲c̲e̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲m̲), see Ch. 12, §3.1; and for argument that this construction involves complementation rather than apposition, see §8.2 below. A sample of nouns licensing declarative content clause complements is given in: [34]...

The noun image is not listed in [34], but since it's only a sample of such nouns, image can be included.
